# Автодополнение Python 3 в Geany

Tags: python, autocomplete, geany

Я хочу поставить данный модуль в Geany по приложенной инструкции https://github.com/notetau/geany-jedi-complete

Но я не пойму что мне вводить в качестве аргумента для sudo make install

На даный момент есть стандартное автозавершение, в котором не показаны значения аргументов по умолчанию. А я хочу, чтобы было как на картинке в инструкции.

Comment: Если судить только по README, то можно выполнять `sudo make install` и без аргументов